# T-SQL Finding who attempted to backup the “master” database?

Tags: sql-server, database-backup, sql-server-2016

I'm running `SQL Server 2016`. For the last two nights at 7pm the SQL Server Alert System sent me this alert:

> 'Severity 016: Miscellaneous User Error' DATE/TIME: 8/8/2018 7:02:19
>   PM DESCRIPTION: BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE
>   master. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.
>   COMMENT: (None) JOB RUN: (None)

I can also see the Backup failure message in the Windows System log.

However...

1. I don't have ANY SQL Agent jobs that attempt to backup the "master" database (I've since added one, since I think I need one, but I've set that to run on Saturdays at 2am).
2. NONE of my SQL Agent Jobs failed according to the SQL Agent Log for the last two days.
3. NONE of my maintenance plans reported an error according to the Maintenance Plan History. The only maintenance plan running at 7pm was an Hourly Transaction Log backup of NLProduction (a User Database), it doesn't touch the master database or any of the system databases.
4. The SQL Server Log (Current - 6/7/2018 8:56:00 PM) shows the same error message saying the backup failed.

I can't find WHY the backup failed, because I can't find the log of who initiated the backup. Any suggestions as to how to find WHO attempted the backup and WHY it failed? Thanks.